# How to compare the value contained in a variable and string without case-sensitivity in Smarty 2?

Tags: php, smarty, string-comparison, case-insensitive, smarty2

I'm using Smarty 2 in my website. At one place I'm comparing value contained in a smarty variable with some string value. With my current code the comparison is taking place but it's comparing the value considering the case-sensitivity. I want to perform this string comparison case-insensitively.

I googled a lot for the solution but couldn't get it. Can someone please help me in comparing the string values case-insensitively.

For your reference following is the code I wrote:

```
{if $data.mode_of_transaction == 'paypal'} paid {/if}
```

Thanks in advance. Waiting for your precious replies.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string here is really `paypal` (no utf-8 characters) you can simply use:

```
{if $data.mode_of_transaction|lower == 'paypal'} paid {/if}
```

or

```
{if $data.mode_of_transaction|lower == $otherVariable|lower} paid {/if}
```

in case you have both values in variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but again you are making the string comparison by considering the case-sensitivity. You are comparing the string values for lower case only. I want the comparison of strings case-insensitively. Means the string could be 'paypal' or 'Paypal' or 'PayPal' or 'PAYPAL' or any other combination of lower and upper case characters. The main objective is to check whether the variable $data.mode_of_transaction contains the word 'paypal'(in any case) or not. How to achieve this in Smarty? Hope you will help me this time too. Thanks once again.

Comment: @user2839497 The above code will do exactly what you want. It will convert your string to lower and compare it so all combinations comparing `paypal` with `PAYPAL`, `Paypal`, 'pAYPAL` and so on will return `true`